# Where to map RestTemplate ResponseEntity objects to Domain objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

In my Repository, I'm calling external REST API and properly retrieve response which I wrap in `ResponseEntity` object as below:

```
    ResponseEntity<ExternalModelResponse> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl + "/api/externalObject", ExternalModelResponse.class);
```

However, `ExternalModelResponse` doesn't follow my Domain model so I want to introduce mapping of the ExternalModelResponse -> Domain model.

What would be the correct place to introduce such mapping? Should:

1. Repository method already return Domain object? That would imply mapping in the same method which fetched object from external REST API.
2. Repository method return `ExternalModelResponse` and let Service handle the mapping?

What is the most common place of such mapping?:

1. added as `toDomainEntity` method on ExternalModelResponse?
2. added as `fromExternalModelResponse` method on Domain Entity?
3. added as a method on Repository/Service ?

Comment: Why is a Repository calling a 3rd party REST api? That looks strange to me since usually repositories are an interface with a database. Have you considered moving that rest call into a dedicated service?

Comment: No, repository is a layer that returns a data, no matter the source.

Comment: I don't agree. No matter the source based on the type of data storage, but I think calling a REST api is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The service layer should use only domain objects, so I've done this mapping in the controllers.